# Something wrong with gatsby theme createPage in tutorial

Tags: reactjs, themes, gatsby

I have been following the tutorial for building your own Gatsby theme, and have reached this step: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/building-a-theme/#set-up-sitegatsby-configjs

When I run `yarn workspace site develop` I get the following:

```
"blog-theme" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

[true-case-path]: Called with .yarn/$$virtual/blog-theme-virtual-074db21a6c/1/blog-theme/src/templates/events.js, but no matching file exists

  45 | exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }, options) => {
  46 |     const basePath = options.basePath || "/"
> 47 |     actions.createPage({
     |             ^
  48 |         path: basePath,
  49 |         component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/events.js`),
  50 |     })

File: ../.yarn/$$virtual/blog-theme-virtual-074db21a6c/1/blog-theme/gatsby-node.js:47:13
```

My code matches the tutorial example, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Something isn't right with the `component` I think.

Comment: The error message indicates `no matching file exists`. Something is wrong with the path to your template file `events.js`. Is the path correct? Is it a React component that renders a page?

Comment: The path was correct. I did `yarn rebuild` and it solved this particular problem.